# Selenium can't find dynamic web element

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to write a Selenium test script in Java for a web application. The application has a button which dynamically adds a form field onto the screen. The problem I've been having is that I can't seem to get the Selenium Web Driver to recognize the new form element element. I first tried initializing the elements in the constructor using @FindBy like this:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "#WIN_0_536870929") private WebElement form;
```

Then, I tried using an explicit wait to make sure the element was loaded (on the button which adds the form to the DOM):

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(this.getDriver(), 20);
WebElement formButton = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("WIN_0_536870929")));
formButton.click();
```

But either way, the dynamic form elements fail to load. There error I get is as follows:

*org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"#WIN_0_817000996"}*

Even more confusing, when I step through the test in the debugger, the form field is fully loaded into the DOM before the test tries to access it.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: please check for any frames or iframes in which that form might be contained...

Comment: did you try to access the form by id?

Comment: Selenium is usually the best approach for dealing with dynamic contents. Can you share the code you are working on and the url of the page ?

Comment: So you are having some problem, using some script, on some application, somewhere? And you would like us to give you a specific solution? Have a careful read through [ask] and follow the instructions!

Comment: @SiKing This question was updated a long time ago. Does it meet your standards now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out I was trying to access an element that was in an iframe. Big thanks to Vivek Singh for suggesting I look into that. I was able to get into the iframe using this line of code:

```
this.driver.switchTo().frame(this.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#WIN_0_817000899 iframe")));
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to define your WebElement only if you are expecting for its visibility:

```
public static WebElement waitForVisibleElement( WebDriver driver, By locator, int timeOutInSeconds ) {
        WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait( driver, timeOutInSeconds );
        try {
            return wdw.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator) );
        } catch ( NoSuchElementException | TimeoutException | NullPointerException ex ) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```